# applying jade template in node.js express website

Tags: node.js, express, pug

given a jade template how does one apply it? The template engine example on jade website just shows the transformation from jade template content to html. It does not show the steps to create this transformation.  Does the file need to be saved with a certain extension and then run somehow? Please clarify the steps thanks.

Update: Basically I am just asking do i save it off as mytemplate.jade and then run this file somehow?  How does it work>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easier way to go forward is to create an express app using the `express` command line.

After that, in the App.js, express by registers jade as the default template engine:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Now in your request handlers, you return something like:

```
res.render('index');
```

Express will try finding index.jade in the Views folder. You could pass any view name in the render parameter and express will do the work for you.

If you want to dwell deeper, you could add more template engines too e.g. On top of Jade, you want to use HAML too, so you'll add this line in the app.configure function:

```
 app.register('.haml', require('hamljs'));
```

This way you are telling that all .haml extensions should be parsed using hamljs. If you want to render a haml view then you'll add the file extension too:

```
res.render('index.haml');
```

When there is no file extension, it will use jade.

You can check out my very simple example, where I am using coffeekup as my template engine at:
https://github.com/neebz/Real-Time-Notice-Board